# html5 download attribute won't work in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

i have a javascript code to construct download link:

```
<a download="report.csv" href="data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,(data appended here)"></a>
```

when i click it, it download the file as 'download' instead of 'report.csv'. I doubt if that's because my browser doesn't support html5 since download attribute is a html5 feature. then i test my browser (chrome) it shows it support html5. any one know why it won't work? thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem with chrome 46.0.2490.80; no charset, simple link

Answer (score 0):

If I do remember correctly, `charset` attribute is not supported anymore in HTML5.

You can try to append the data converted to base64